# Connection Apple TV to the analog audio stereo speakers

Tags: appletv, audio

I have a projector with HDMI connection and speakers with analog audio jack.

I've bought Apple TV and I'm going to connect the projector with HDMI.

However, I'm afraid I need to buy an adapter for the Apple TV optical audio interface to connect the jack of my stereo.

[image]

Could you give me more info about it ?

Comment: Does your stereo support toshlink or mini toshlink?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK

Comment: [Similar question][1] was asked earlier.


  [1]: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43003/can-i-direct-the-audio-signal-from-apple-tv/43025#43025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to buy an adapter.

The Apple TV only offers digital audio and video outputs.

Answer (score 2):

HDMI to VGA + Audio:
http://store.apple.com/us/product/H9139VC/A/kanex-atv-pro-hdmi-to-vga-adapter-with-audio-support

Digital Coax / Optical Toslink to Analog Audio:
[http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Optical-Toslink-Analog-Converter/dp/B004C4WPXA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004C4WPXA)

I like the HDMI solution - it's an unpowered device; however it's considerably more expensive.  Maybe try dx.com for a slightly cheaper alternative (search hdmi vga audio).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the projector, it may have a pass through for audio, so that may be an alternative to an adapter.

Comment: The projects only has RCA audio outputs. I'm afraid I need an adapter as well from RCA to stereo output jack. Correct ?

Comment: Yes, but RCA to 3.5mm adapters are very cheap, whereas going from the digital out on the Apple TV will require an active adapter, adding to the cost and complexity. Check out [Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com) for good quality cheap adapters.

Comment: But if I just want to listen to music with airPlay, I have to switch on the projector everytime?